# Datatables.net MVC JavaScript Populated table erroneously shows Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, datatable

First time using DataTables.net with MVC and JavaScript. On my .cshtml page I have a Datatables.net table that correctly brings back data and populates the table using JavaScript. (I have copied this from another example that also brings back data correctly and populates the table.) My problem is that at the bottom of the table it erroneously shows Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries despite displaying multiple rows of information. (on the example that I copied from it correctly shows 1 of 20 entries).

My code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
function getTransactionListingHistory(contactCode) {
    var groupColumn = 1;

    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#datatableTransactionHistory')) {
        table = $('#datatableTransactionHistory').DataTable();
        table.destroy();
    }

    var historyTable = $('#datatableTransactionHistory').DataTable({
        order: [0, "desc"],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "filter": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Transactions/TransactionsGetData?contactCode=" + contactCode,
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        columnDefs: [
            //{ "targets": [1], "visible": false, "searchable": false }
        ],
        "columns": [
            {
               "data": "lineDate", "name": "LineDate", "autoWidth": true,
                 
            },               
            {
                "data": "lineReference", "name": "lineReference", "autoWidth": true,
                "render": function(data, type, row) {               

                    return data;
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "formattedDebitAmount", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "",
                "render": function(data, type, row) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        return "<a class='text-danger text-right text-nowrap'>" + data + "</a>";
                    }
                }
            },    
            {
                "data": "LineID",                 "name": "lineID",                 "autoWidth": true, 
                "render": function(data, type, row)  
                {
                    
                        return '<a onclick="repeatTransaction(' + '\'' +  row.lineID + '\');"  href="#" id="repeat-link"><img src="' + "/images/icons/refresh.svg" + '" />&nbsp;' +  'Repeat' + '</a>';
                        
                }
            }, 
        ],
        fixedHeader: true,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500], [10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500]],
        "iDisplayLength": @myPagingSize,
        language: {
            processing: "<div style='color: #ff6611!important;' class='spinner-border text-warning m-2' role='status' aria-hidden='true'></div>&emsp;Processing ...",
            paginate: {
                next: '<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>',
                previous: '<i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>'
            }
        }
    });

    $('#datatableTransactionHistoryul.pagination').addClass("pagination-rounded");

    
};    
</script>
```

Comment: You are using `"serverSide": true`. Do you need that option?

Comment: When using the `"serverSide": true` option (e.g. because you have very large volumes of data) you are telling DataTables that your server (not DataTables) will handle sorting, filtering and pagination. If you use `"serverSide": true` and if [your JSON response](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) from the server does not contain the pagination info needed by DataTables, then you will see incorrect "Showing n to n of n entries" information.

Comment: Thank you lots for the explanations. I thought the datasets might be large. I've set the "serverSide": false and even removed the property but in both instances I get the error:
DataTables warning: table id=datatableTransactionHistory - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: Edit: I'll also look into my controller to see if it returns the pagination info needed by DataTables.

Comment: You do not need any of that pagination info in your JSON if you are not using `serverSide: true`. You just need the data, as a valid JSON array of arrays or a JSON array of objects. You should follow the troubleshooting guidance in [that link](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7) you get.

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames I kept the serverSite: true and checked in my controller and saw that I wasn't keeping score of the totals. After adding each item to the response I updated the response with response.TotalTransactions += 1. Now it correctly displays "Showing x to y of z entries". Much appreciative of your advice and explanations.